# Change physics based on group - visjs

Tags: javascript, graph, vis.js-network, vis.js

I would like to make some groups of nodes in my Graph behave differently than the other nodes.
For example I have a group called "properties" that I dynamicly add to the graph. I need to change the gravity constants or weights for this group so they are closer to the parent then the rest of the nodes.

[image: example]

I hope this example helps visualize the problem. (Had to black out the labels because of sensitive info)

How would I accomplish this in vis.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//

Hi Json.

see the attached code snippet.
hope it helps you.

```js
// create an array with nodes
  var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: 'Node 1', group: 1},
    {id: 2, label: 'Node 2', group: 2},
    {id: 3, label: 'Node 3', group: 1},
    {id: 4, label: 'Node 4', group: 2},
    {id: 5, label: 'Node 5', group: 2}
  ]);

  // create an array with edges
  var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    {from: 1, to: 3},
    {from: 2, to: 4},
    {from: 2, to: 5}
  ]);

  // create a network
  var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  };
  var options = {
    groups: {
      1: { color: 'red', mass: 500 },// try to change this value
      2: { color: 'blue', mass: 5 }
    },
    physics: true
  };
  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

```css
#mynetwork {
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
    }

    p {
      max-width: 600px;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Network | Basic usage</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.20.0/vis.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.20.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any way to use something like this with an other physics model? Like "forceAtlas2Based"?

Comment: @Jason as far as i understand it should be the same.
try to add:
"edges": {
    "smooth": {
      "forceDirection": "none"
    }
  },
  "physics": {
    "forceAtlas2Based": {
      "centralGravity": 0.03,
      "springLength": 100
    },
    "minVelocity": 0.75,
    "solver": "forceAtlas2Based"
  }
to your options.